# Service port accessible only by one network card

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, port, network-share, service

I have server 08 R2 with two network cards. One is for the internal network (10.1.1.x) and another for internet (192.168.1.X connected to the modem). Network clients always accessed a service in this server by a certain port 9999 through the internal network 10.1.1.x: 9999, but after having to reinstall this service it is no longer available by the internal IP address (10.1.1.x) only by external (192.168.1.X). If a client machine, eg: 10.1.1.79 try a telnet 10.1.1.X 9999 can not access, but if you try to telnet 192.168.1.X 9999 it works! The problem is I need this service run via internal IP (10.1.1.x) as worked before. Another observation is that if I try start the service with external network card disabled (192.168.1.X), service returns error . How do I bind this service to internal network card? I have serious network problem because this problem :(

Comment: What error does the service return?

Comment: The windows can not start the service NTSquid on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process was terminated unexpectedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the windows firewall (Server 08). For some reason he was locking door 3128 by internal NIC. I created an inbound rule and resolved.